# Avoid taxonomy-%term%.php if more than one taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, template-hierarchy

I have a site with multiple custom taxonomies which are used for filtering posts.

One of the taxonomies has a `taxonomy-%term%.php` template file.

`/?country=the_country` shows the country taxonomy template

but `/?topic=the_topic&country=the_country` uses the country taxonomy template as well.

Is there a simple way to avoid loading the `taxonomy-country.php` template if more than one taxonomy is being queried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was found by (as [jaswrks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/81760/jaswrks) has mentioned) removing the `taxonomy-country.php` file entirely.

The contents of `taxonomy-country.php` are then loaded conditionally within taxonomy.php

Custom post_types & taxonomies have an option to "rewrite" the urls. In this case, the same url parameters that are filtering the taxonomy archives were sometimes colliding with this url-schema and causing unwanted results.

The simple answer would be to disable rewriting the urls of the problem taxonomies.

But a cleaner option turned out to be to

```
remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
```

... which can be used to disable the `rewrite` attribute from custom post_types or taxonomies

Answer (score 1):

See: [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png)

My suggestion would be to move away from term-specific template files in this case, and instead use only `taxonomy.php`, where in that file you can work out the logic you need to in order to render the proper output; i.e., you can then detect the use of multiple taxonomies and adjust as necessary.

Comment: Yup, I'll post an answer soon. I'm only using `archive.php` and had added conditionals to load the specifix taxo template... But the icing on the cake: was adding an extra url-param that only applies when the archives are being filtered. Without that, there was no way to distinguish between the ?country being applied as a filter to the archive output and ?country being applied to call the template/partial